# While dragging a map in Leaflet it marks a point for the feature

Tags: leaflet, angular

In my Leaflet application, When I draw a feature (Line/Polygon) and if I need to drag the base map to mark a point outside the visibility of the map then Leaflet marks additional point where I tap on the map to drag, which is not the expected behavior.

Code for marking line in typescript:

```
this.l_PolylineDrawer = new L.Draw.Polyline((this.map as L.DrawMap),{showLength : true,icon : this.icon,
      shapeOptions: {color:'#ffcc33',stroke:true}});
```

Comment: And what is the question/problem?

Comment: If I want to mark a line where the next point is outside the visibility of the map and I need to drag the map in this case the l_PolylineDrawer marks a point where I tabbed to drag the map as well, Which shall not be the case.

Comment: Please update your question with the additional explanation from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be a bug, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/695. This bug report has also a hack that should work, just put it before any draw code:

```
(function() {
  var originalOnTouch = L.Draw.Polyline.prototype._onTouch;
  L.Draw.Polyline.prototype._onTouch = function( e ) {
    if( e.originalEvent.pointerType != 'mouse'  && e.originalEvent.pointerType != 'touch' ) {
      return originalOnTouch.call(this, e);
    }
  }
})();
```

I could test it only on regular non-touch device and there it works.

Here si working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/5sLuyco0/

Comment: L.Draw.Polyline.prototype is not defined in L.Draw.Polyline class hence typescript throws compile time error.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, probably connected with Angular environment (with which I'm not familiar with). See modified answer with JSFiddle example.